# Flag declined but still applied?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

A few months ago I've asked for answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958491/get-cookie-with-file-get-contents-in-php) to be merged with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797510/file-get-contents-receive-cookies).

The questions are now merged (thanks to Gordon), but my flag history now states:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

If the request was acted upon, why would it ever be declined?

Comment: It was declined by another moderator... after it was merged. What.

Comment: Moderators can simply clear flags if the work has previously been done, right?

Comment: Yes, as helpful. I don't know why he chose to decline this instead. Maybe it really was a slip-up, because we get so many dud flags these days it's hard to tell anymore.

Comment: Guessing Gordon just forgot to clear the flag, and it ended up looking weird sitting their on a stub with no answers... We should probably make merging clear all pending flags, as this isn't even the worst thing that can happen (answer flags and comment flags start behaving very strangely if you reparent the question while they're still live).